# How do I solve the MySQL error where I Cannot add foreign key constraint because of ERROR 1215?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

This is my first table.

```
CREATE TABLE `raw_orders` (
`row_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`order_id` VARCHAR(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`order_revenue` FLOAT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`row_id`),
KEY(`order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

This is my second table

```
CREATE TABLE `formatted_orders` (
`order_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`client_order_id` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
`order_revenue` FLOAT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`order_id`),
KEY(`client_order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I am trying to add foreign key in formatted_orders linking it to raw_orders by using this

```
ALTER TABLE formatted_orders 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (client_order_id) REFERENCES raw_orders(order_id);
```

But I get this error

> ERROR (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: So did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot add the constraint is because you specify different collations for the columns in the two tables. Also, the columns should be the same size, although MySQL will let you create the constraint even if they're not.

Change to the same collation (`COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci` for instance) for both columns and it will work.

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8360e5) for an example.

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) states that:

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
>   have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be
>   the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For
>   nonbinary (character) string columns, **the character set and collation
>   must be the same**.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a foreign key in the table `formatted_orders` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `formatted_orders` (
`order_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`client_order_id` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
`order_revenue` FLOAT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`order_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`client_order`) REFERENCES raw_orders(`order_id`)
)
```